# Specify which theme to use when rendering a page with drupal_render_page()

Tags: 7, batch-operations, theming

I'm looking to send out a node as an HTML email. I have the code working except for one part.

I'm using [drupal_render_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_page/7) to render the page's content so it's ready for an HTML email. I thought I'd use a custom theme for this (to take advantage of Drupal's theming layer).

However, I can't seem to figure out how I would specify a specific theme to use. Every time I run it it runs the current theme.

I'm not sure if this make a difference or not, but I'm using the [Batch API](http://drupal.org/node/180528) to generate/send the emails.

I've tried changing the [$theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/theme/7) and [$theme_key](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/theme_key/7) globals in the batch callback, however that didn't seem to change anything.

I've also tried something like this in [hook_custom_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7):

```
if (arg(0) == 'batch' && $_REQUEST['op'] == 'do') {
  return 'email';
}
```

However, this also doesn't seem to change anything and still renders the email using the "seven" theme.

I've also tried using [hook_batch_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_batch_alter/7), however changing the theme changes it for the batch process, (I still want the batch to process in the seven theme, I just want the email to be rendered in a different theme).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that [menu_get_custom_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_custom_theme/7) only uses a custom theme if the menu does NOT have a "theme callback". In the case of the batch process, it does have a theme callback: [_system_batch_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/_system_batch_theme/7).

To specify what theme to use when rendering a batch process, I had to use [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to change the theme callback to my own.

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {

  $items['batch']['theme callback'] = 'MYMODULE_batch_theme';

}
```

Then I just needed to add a conditional

```
function MYMODULE_batch_theme() {

  // Use a Custom Theme
  if ($_REQUEST['op'] == 'do') {
    return 'email';
  }
  else {
    return _system_batch_theme();
  }

}
```

This fixes the problem by specify the custom theme in the theme callback rather than in [hook_custom_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7) (which is ignored when a theme callback is present).

Thanks!

Comment: I was _just_ about to ask this, myself, and this popped up in similar questions and it was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!